# android 3.0 bluetooth file transfer issue

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have an application that use the bluetooth to receive a file from an external device. That file has his own extension.
My app works fine on android 2.2 .The external device sends the file and the android-device receives the file. No problem with that. 
The problem now is with android 3.0, because he refuse to accept the file transfer.
Someone can explain me why?
I mean, is there any kind of check during the bluetooth file transfer? Does android 3.0 control the file type before the start of the transfer?
Thanks